# Which do i need Sendgrid or Mailkit - to send emails from azure webjob

Tags: console-application, .net-core, sendgrid, azure-webjobs, mailkit

Can i use Mailkit to send emails from an azure webjob using an organizational smtp server? Or do i need to use Sendgrid?

Mine is a .net core 1.1 console application which i then hosted as azure webjob.

For some reason, I am not able to get my webjob working with Mailkit using an organizational Smtp server. The job runs successfully, does not log any errors. BUT not able to send mails out..

here is my code that uses mailkit

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    try { 
    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;


        Logger.LogInformation("Ready to connect to smtp server");
        client.Connect(Constants.SMTP_HOST, 25, false);
        Logger.LogInformation("connected to smtp server");
        // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
        // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

        Logger.LogInformation("Ready to send email");
        client.Send(message);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.LogError("An error occurred");
        Logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally {
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use Mailkit to send emails from an azure webjob using an organizational smtp server?

If you use the organizational smtp server, then should make sure that your email server policy allowed to that.

I test Mailkit in the Azure WebJob with **google** email. It works correctly on my side. Before that I turn  `Allow less secure apps:` ON for my gmail account

[image]

The following is the demo code.

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Tom Gmail", "xx@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Tom Hotmail", "xxx@hotmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "I am a mail subject";

            message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = "I am a mail body."
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {

                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);


                // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
                // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("sunguiguan@gmail.com", "@WSX3edc");

                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("send mail successful");
            Console.Read();
```

[image]

> Or do i need to use Sendgrid?

On my opinon, SendGrid also is a good choice, we also could use the free price tier on the Azure. I also test it on myside. it also works correctly. We also could get more detail info from azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email#overview).

```
     var apiKey ="ApiKey";//System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_APIKEY");
     var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
     var msg = new SendGridMessage()
     {
               From = new EmailAddress("xxx@hotmail.com", "Send Grid"),
                Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
                PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("xxxx@gmail.com", "Test User"));
            client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Wait();
    }
```